# How to extract an attribute using xml-fast-parser

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I can extract elements from parsed XML like so:

```
import { XMLParser } from "fast-xml-parser";

let xml = '<gpx myAttr="fred"><trk>track 1</trk><trk>track 2<trkpt>trackpoint 2</trkpt></trk></gpx>';
const options = {
  ignoreAttributes: false,
  attributeNamePrefix : "@_"
};
const parser = new XMLParser(options);
const root = parser.parse(xml);

const track0 = root.gpx.trk[0];           // gives 'track 1'
const trackpoint = root.gpx.trk[1].trkpt; // gives 'trackpoint 2'
const attr = root.gpx.myAttr;             // gives 'undefined'
```

but trying to get the attribute doesn't work. Because of the parser's `attributeNamePrefix` I have also tried

```
 const attr = root.gpx.@_myAttr;
```

but of course that gives a syntax error. After I extract an attribute I want to modify it and recreate the XML using `XMLBuilder`, so I will need something like

```
root.gpx.myAttr = "newAttr";
```

There a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jqhovynt/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you put into JSFiddle seems mostly correct. However, there is a syntax error in the XML string; the closing tag for `<trk>` is missing. Here's the corrected code:

Corrected JSFiddle:

```js
// let xml = '<gpx myAttr="fred"><trk>track 1</trk><trk>track 2<trkpt>trackpoint 2</trkpt></trk></gpx>';
let xml =
  '<gpx myAttr="fred"><trk>track 1</trk><trk>track 2</trk><trkpt>trackpoint 2</trkpt></trk></gpx>';
const options = {
  ignoreAttributes: false,
  attributeNamePrefix: '@_', // you have assign this so use this to access the attribute
};
const parser = new XMLParser(options);
const root = parser.parse(xml);

const track0 = root.gpx.trk[0];
const trackpoint = root.gpx.trk[1].trkpt;
// const attr = root.gpx.myAttr
const attr = root.gpx['@_myAttr']; // Use the correct attribute name

document.getElementById('trk1').innerHTML = track0;
document.getElementById('trk2').innerHTML = trackpoint;
document.getElementById('attr').innerHTML = attr;
```

Changes made:

1. Corrected the missing closing tag for  in the xml string.
2. Used `root.gpx['@_myAttr']` instead of `root.gpx.myAttr` to access the attribute with the correct name.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure what happened to the closing tag, it looked OK to me. But you've shown me how to use the square brckets for the attribute. Great!